# Can't send direct message to user using Spring Boot Websocket Stomp

Tags: java, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

I have a client server application implemented in Spring Boot 3. It uses web socket with stomp to communicate with each other. Currently both the server and client are implemented using different versions of Spring and Spring Boot.

I was successful with sending messages using a common topic to each other. The messages are encrypted so only the intended client can decrypt it and view it.

The application is intended for more complicated purposes but for my purpose let me present it to you as a chat application.

This is part of the code which tests the functionality:
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

```
@Autowired
private ActiveUserStore activeUserStore;

@MessageMapping("/send")
@SendToUser("/queue/chat")
public void sendToUser(@Payload WsIncomingMessage wsIncomingMessage, Principal user, @Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) {
    log.info(" /queue/chat > incoming msg: {}, user: {}, header: {}", wsIncomingMessage, user, sessionId);
    WsOutgoingMessage wsOutgoingMessage = new WsOutgoingMessage();
    wsOutgoingMessage.setMessage(wsIncomingMessage.getMessage());
    wsOutgoingMessage.setMessageType(wsIncomingMessage.getMessageType());
    wsOutgoingMessage.setSentDatetime(wsIncomingMessage.getSentDatetime());
    wsOutgoingMessage.setSource(wsIncomingMessage.getSource());
    wsOutgoingMessage.setDestination(wsIncomingMessage.getDestination());
    wsIncomingMessage.setAdId(wsIncomingMessage.getAdId());
    log.info(" /queue/chat > outgoing msg: {}, user: {}, header: {}", wsIncomingMessage, user, sessionId);
    
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(activeUserStore.getUser(wsOutgoingMessage.getDestination()).getPrincipal(), "/queue/chat", wsOutgoingMessage);
}
```

Calling `activeUserStore.getUser(wsOutgoingMessage.getDestination()).getPrincipal()` returns a phone number which identifies the user. We think the phone number in full path uniquely identifies the user.

My handshaker:

```
@Slf4j
public class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler { 

    
    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
            Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Principal pinciplal = request.getPrincipal();

        if (pinciplal instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) pinciplal;
            Object principalObj = usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
            if (principalObj instanceof JwtUserDetails) {
                JwtUserDetails connectingUser = (JwtUserDetails) principalObj;
                connectingUser.setSessionUuid(uuid);
                
            }
        }
        log.info("principal in CustomHandshakeHandler: {}", pinciplal);
        return pinciplal;
    }
}
```

The string representation of the principal: `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=JwtUserDetails(id=3, name=Anupam, principal=+855964572928, password=, sessionUuid=0c4169cd-0289-4233-a6f4-0ec04ea3d08c, authorities=[JwtGrantedAuthority(authorityName=USER)]), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[JwtGrantedAuthority(authorityName=USER)]]`

The Spring Boot Server is receiving stomp messages. I think it is also returning messages but I don't know how to log the returned messages:

```
[boundChannel-13][0;39m [36mc.l.c.f.k.c.controller.ChatController   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m  /queue/chat > incoming msg: WsIncomingMessage(message=Hi, messageType=text/plain, destination=4, sentDatetime=2023-04-29T10:39:49+07:00, source=3, sourceImage=0, adId=no-ad), user: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=JwtUserDetails(id=3, name=Anupam, principal=+855964572928, password=, sessionUuid=0c4169cd-0289-4233-a6f4-0ec04ea3d08c, authorities=[JwtGrantedAuthority(authorityName=USER)]), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[JwtGrantedAuthority(authorityName=USER)]], header: 36d934da-79d7-f00b-6459-331f1cef60ca

[boundChannel-13][0;39m [36mc.l.c.f.k.c.controller.ChatController   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m  /queue/chat > outgoing msg: WsIncomingMessage(message=Hi, messageType=text/plain, destination=4, sentDatetime=2023-04-29T10:39:49+07:00, source=3, sourceImage=0, adId=no-ad), user: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=JwtUserDetails(id=3, name=Anupam, principal=+855964572928, password=, sessionUuid=0c4169cd-0289-4233-a6f4-0ec04ea3d08c, authorities=[JwtGrantedAuthority(authorityName=USER)]), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[JwtGrantedAuthority(authorityName=USER)]], header: 36d934da-79d7-f00b-6459-331f1cef60ca
```

The server is registering subscribe events:

```
event: SessionSubscribeEvent[GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={simpMessageType=SUBSCRIBE, stompCommand=SUBSCRIBE, nativeHeaders={destination=[/user/queue/chat], id=[0]}, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpHeartbeat=[J@197209d9, simpSubscriptionId=0, simpUser=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=JwtUserDetails(id=3, name=Anupam, principal=+855964572928, password=, sessionUuid=0c4169cd-0289-4233-a6f4-0ec04ea3d08c, authorities=[JwtGrantedAuthority(authorityName=USER)]), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[JwtGrantedAuthority(authorityName=USER)]], simpSessionId=36d934da-79d7-f00b-6459-331f1cef60ca, simpDestination=/user/queue/chat}]]
```

The client can also see the success of subscription:

```
StompSession.Subscription messageSubscriberSubscription = sessionStomp.get().subscribe("/user/queue/chat", messageSubscriber);
log.info("messageSubscriberSubscription: {}", messageSubscriberSubscription);

10:39:43.244 [Grizzly(2)] INFO com.lomatechnology.cambodia.fintech.kke.chat.web.ServerCommunication -- messageSubscriberSubscription: Subscription [id=0, destination='/user/queue/chat', receiptId='null', handler=com.lomatechnology.cambodia.fintech.kke.chat.web.MessageSubscriber@39fe1782]
10:39:49.022 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.lomatechnology.cambodia.fintech.kke.chat.util.DatetimeUtil -- Returned date string: 2023-04-29T10:39:49+07:00
10:39:49.022 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.lomatechnology.cambodia.fintech.kke.chat.ui.ChatGui -- About to send: WsOutgoingMessage(message=Hi, messageType=text/plain, destination=4, sourceImage=null, sentDatetime=2023-04-29T10:39:49+07:00, source=3, adId=no-ad)
```

The only problem is that the intended client is never receiving messages. Is it the wrong use of principle in `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser` or hace I missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define `userDestinationPrefix`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user"); // DEFINE HERE
    //topic added again to handle SubscribeMapping
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app", "/topic");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addEndpoint("/ws")
        .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
        .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
        .withSockJS();
  }
}
```

CustomHandshakeHandler:

```
public class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
  // Custom class for storing principal
  @Override
  protected Principal determineUser(
      ServerHttpRequest request,
      WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
      Map<String, Object> attributes
  ) {
    // Generate principal with UUID as name
    return new StompPrincipal(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
  }
}
```

Finally to send messages to specific user:

```
 messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                  user.getName(), "/queue/player", new PlayerState(gameObjectState));
```

Full example of sending message:

```
 @MessageMapping("/game/{room}")
  public void handleGameUpdates(
      @DestinationVariable String room,
      @Payload GameObjectState gameObjectState,
      Principal principal) {

    // Get all the users in the application
    Collection<SimpUser> users = simpUserRegistry.getUsers();

    for (SimpUser user : users) {
      for (SimpSession session : user.getSessions()) {
        if (session.getSubscriptions().stream()
            .anyMatch(subscription -> subscription.getDestination().endsWith(room))) {
          // If the user is subscribed to the room, add their userId to the list
          if (!user.getName().equals(principal.getName())) {
            if (gameObjectState.getType().equals(GameObjectType.PLAYER)) {
              messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                  user.getName(), "/queue/player", new PlayerState(gameObjectState));
            } else {
              messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                  user.getName(), "/queue/bullet", new BulletState(gameObjectState));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

if you need more check the repo: https://github.com/gurkanucar/websockets/blob/main/stomp%20spring%20boot%20example/socket_detailed/src/main/java/com/gucardev/socket_detailed/config/WebSocketConfig.java

Comment: Let me try that out.